# WebdriverIO - Edit test title or property with spec reporter

Tags: mocha.js, webdriver-io

Is there a way to easily override spec reporter to edit `Running` property?
My use case is that I have 2 capabilities object of chrome which only differ the mobile emulation because one is purely desktop size, and the other one is a chrome simulating mobile size.
The issue is in the spec reporter there is no way for me to tell which runner was the mobile or desktop. I get an output similar to this:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
[chrome 88.0.4324.96 LINUX #0-0] Spec: /path/to/spec.js
[chrome 88.0.4324.96 LINUX #0-0] Running: chrome (v88.0.4324.96) on LINUX
[chrome 88.0.4324.96 LINUX #0-0] Session ID: 27fe3f66-0197-4e26-ad76-dedbbb442ef5
[chrome 88.0.4324.96 LINUX #0-0]
[chrome 88.0.4324.96 LINUX #0-0] Suite 1
[chrome 88.0.4324.96 LINUX #0-0]    ✓ Test Case #1
[chrome 88.0.4324.96 LINUX #0-0]
[chrome 88.0.4324.96 LINUX #0-0] 1 passing (7.4s)
------------------------------------------------------------------
[chrome 88.0.4324.96 LINUX #1-0] Spec: /path/to/spec.js
[chrome 88.0.4324.96 LINUX #1-0] Running: chrome (v88.0.4324.96) on LINUX
[chrome 88.0.4324.96 LINUX #1-0] Session ID: 8091a4f4-5133-453b-b14a-bd9f814165a8
[chrome 88.0.4324.96 LINUX #1-0]
[chrome 88.0.4324.96 LINUX #1-0] Suite 1
[chrome 88.0.4324.96 LINUX #1-0]    ✓ Test Case #1
[chrome 88.0.4324.96 LINUX #1-0]
[chrome 88.0.4324.96 LINUX #1-0] 1 passing (7.9s)


Spec Files:      2 passed, 2 total (100% completed) in 00:00:14
```

I also tried to edit the suite title on before hooks, but without success. If someone can help me with an easy way to approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a custom reporter and override the `getHeaderDisplay` method to achieve that.

For instance:

1. Create the `my-custom-reporter.js` file
2. Import the `SpecReporter` reporter
3. Declare the `CustomReporter` class that extends the `SpecReproter` reporter
4. Declare the `getHeaderDisplay` method
5. Add information about mobile in the `output` array
6. Export the module
7. In the `wdio.conf.js` config import the custom spec reporter
8. Add it in the `reporters` array, `reporters: [[CustomReporter]],`

Full working example:

In the `my-custom-reporter.js` file:

```
const { default: SpecReporter } = require('@wdio/spec-reporter')

class CustomReporter extends SpecReporter {
    getHeaderDisplay(runner) {
        const combo = this.getEnviromentCombo(runner.capabilities, undefined, runner.isMultiremote).trim();
        // Here we get information about mobile device
        const mobileInfo = runner.config.capabilities['goog:chromeOptions']?.mobileEmulation?.deviceName
            ? `${runner.config.capabilities['goog:chromeOptions'].mobileEmulation.deviceName} emulated by`
            : '';
        const output = [
            `Spec: ${runner.specs[0]}`,
            `Running: ${mobileInfo} ${combo}`
        ];
    
        if (runner.capabilities.sessionId) output.push(`Session ID: ${runner.capabilities.sessionId}`);
    
        return output;
    }
}

module.exports = CustomReporter;
```

In the `wdio.conf.js` file:

```
const CustomReporter = require('./my-custom-reporter')

exports.config = {
    // ... other properties
    reporters: [[CustomReporter]],
}
```

Output:

```
[chrome 89.0.4389.90 mac os x #0-0] Spec: /Users/u/test/specs/example.e2e.ts
[chrome 89.0.4389.90 mac os x #0-0] Running:  chrome (v89.0.4389.90) on mac os x
[chrome 89.0.4389.90 mac os x #0-0] Session ID: f0480174d634514e5559e560188d2d84
[chrome 89.0.4389.90 mac os x #0-0]
[chrome 89.0.4389.90 mac os x #0-0] My Login application
[chrome 89.0.4389.90 mac os x #0-0]    ✓ should login with valid credentials
[chrome 89.0.4389.90 mac os x #0-0]
[chrome 89.0.4389.90 mac os x #0-0] 1 passing (3.4s)
------------------------------------------------------------------
[chrome 89.0.4389.90 mac os x #1-0] Spec: /Users/u/test/specs/example.e2e.ts
[chrome 89.0.4389.90 mac os x #1-0] Running: iPhone X emulated by chrome (v89.0.4389.90) on mac os x
[chrome 89.0.4389.90 mac os x #1-0] Session ID: a7eacc89e3b933c895e7bf1d5811e72b
[chrome 89.0.4389.90 mac os x #1-0]
[chrome 89.0.4389.90 mac os x #1-0] My Login application
[chrome 89.0.4389.90 mac os x #1-0]    ✓ should login with valid credentials
[chrome 89.0.4389.90 mac os x #1-0]
[chrome 89.0.4389.90 mac os x #1-0] 1 passing (3.5s)


Spec Files: 2 passed, 2 total (100% completed) in 00:00:18
```